# How can I resize a sprite image programmatically according to the position of the image

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, ipad

I have 10 images a ball of same size. I need to show the ball animation. The ball animation should start image1 and should end with image10.
I want to show that the ball is travelled far from the throwing position. So, I need to show that the images at the end of animation are small.
 For this I manually resized the images of the ball.
How can  programmatically scale the images in to smaller size according to the position of the image?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

make a counter. each frame add one to the counter and update the scale of the sprite based off of that counter.

```
    #define scale 5
-(void)foo
{
    if(counter<100)
    {
      counter = counter + 1;
      [ball animatewithframe:counter];
      [ball setScale:(1/counter*scale)]; //this will get smaller and smaller as counter goes to   500

    }
}
```

something like that.